# Override KNP DoctrineBehaviors "under-the-hood"

Tags: php, symfony, overriding, bundle

I'm writing a SEO bundle, which is mainly composed with 2 parts :

- One form extension (for adding slug/title/desc fields in forms)
- One trait Seoable containing thoses fields for the entity side

On top of this I would like to climb on shoulders of KNP DoctrineBehaviors, using the sluggable trait.

My problem : in my architecture, the Sluggable trait would be used by my Seoable trait, not by a final class. In the DoctrineBehaviors' guts, I found that the trait check is done by a ClassAnalyzer class, with this method :

```
/**
     * Return TRUE if the given object use the given trait, FALSE if not
     * @param ReflectionClass $class
     * @param string $traitName
     * @param boolean $isRecursive
     */
    public function hasTrait(\ReflectionClass $class, $traitName, $isRecursive = false)
    {
        if (in_array($traitName, $class->getTraitNames())) {
            return true;
        }

        $parentClass = $class->getParentClass();

        if ((false === $isRecursive) || (false === $parentClass) || (null === $parentClass)) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->hasTrait($parentClass, $traitName, $isRecursive);
    }
```

The recursive part check all ancestors class, but not the traits contained within traits.

2 solutions on the top of my head :

- Submit a pull request on KNP DoctrineBehaviors with this recursive pattern extended to traits (which I eventually will do)
- Overrid this part

DoctrineBehaviors is not a "regular" bundle, meaning not registered in AppKernel. How can I extend this part?

Thanks for your replies,

Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a more attentive reading of [this part of cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#services-configuration), I checked in DoctrineBehaviors config files (vendor/knplabs/doctrine-behaviors/config/orm-services.yml).

KNP provides here all parameters to listeners and classes used in the DoctrineBehaviors bundle, such as :

```
parameters:
    knp.doctrine_behaviors.reflection.class_analyzer.class: Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Reflection\ClassAnalyzer
    knp.doctrine_behaviors.reflection.is_recursive: true
    knp.doctrine_behaviors.translatable_subscriber.class: Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\ORM\Translatable\TranslatableSubscriber
# next...
```

So, I just overrided the first param to use my own ClassAnalyser instance in parameters config.yml section.
For the record, the recursive loop with ancestor traits check :

```
     /**
     * Return TRUE if the given object use the given trait, FALSE if not
     * Extends from ClassAnalyzer::hasTrait to check in ancestors traits as well
     * @param \ReflectionClass $class
     * @param string $traitName
     * @param boolean $isRecursive
     */
    public function hasTrait(\ReflectionClass $class, $traitName, $isRecursive = false)
    {
        $classTraits = $class->getTraitNames();

        // Trait directly present in final class
        if (in_array($traitName, $classTraits)) {
            return true;
        }

        // Check in parents traits
        foreach($classTraits as $classTrait) {
            $traitObject = new \ReflectionClass($classTrait);

            if($this->hasTrait($traitObject, $traitName, $isRecursive)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // Check in parents classes
        $parentClass = $class->getParentClass();

        if ((false === $isRecursive) || (false === $parentClass) || (null === $parentClass)) {
            return false;
        }

        return $this->hasTrait($parentClass, $traitName, $isRecursive);
    }
```